Disable dragging down in Hero animations with NavigationTransitions
I'm using a hero transition and I can't find a way to disable the dragging down dismiss behavior in the second view.
I only want to dismiss the view using a button.
struct HomeView: View {
    var items = ItemsConfiguration.createList()
    
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                            .foregroundStyle(.green)
                            .matchedTransitionSource(id: item.id, in: namespace, configuration: { source in
                                source
                                    .background(.green)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                                    .shadow(radius: 8)
                            })
                            .frame(height: 80)
                            .padding(16)
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: ItemCell.self) { item in
                    DetailView(item: item)
                        .navigationTransition(.zoom(sourceID: item.id, in: namespace))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let item: ItemCell
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:40) {
            Text("Hello Detail View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
            
            Button("Dismiss") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

This is a video evidence about the behavior
